# Expected Value: Card Problem

Tags: probability

There are $\$10$ on the table. Sam bets $\$5$ that the next card is a heart. You bet $\$5$ that it’s a diamond. The card comes clubs and nobody wins. So, now there are $\$20$ on the table. Sam bets $\$5$ again that the next card is a heart. In order to call his bet you have to also pay $\$5$ and bet on a different suit, for example, that the card is a diamond. The bets and calls get added to the table and the winner gets what’s on the table.

What is the expected value?

What I tried for this was $(13/52 \times 25.00) - (39/52 \times 5.00) = 2.50$

Is my intuition correct for this?

Comment: You are asking whether 2.50 is the correct answer to what question???

Comment: Ah sorry, the expected value*

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the card isn't put back into the deck, the expected value would be:
$$\frac{13}{51}\cdot25+\frac{38}{51}\cdot(-5)=\frac{325-190}{51}=\frac{135}{51}\approx2.647$$

Comment: Ah, this makes much more sense to me. Thank you, did not consider the card staying out of the deck.